# MS Word: Add 30 days to current date field

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to create a field that when the Word file is opened automatically displays the current date + 30 days in the format 11/04/2016.

I have looked into the non-trivial field format but it doesn't display anything:

```
{ QUOTE "{ SET " Delay" "30" }
{  SET "DaysInMonth" { IF { CreateDate \@ "MM" } <> 2 
{  = ROUND(30.575*{ CreateDate \@ "MM" },0)-
ROUND(30.575*{ = { CreateDate \@ "MM" } -1 },0) }
{  IF {  = MOD( { CreateDate \@"yy" } , 4 ) } > 0 "28" "29" } } }
{ SET "NextMonth" {  IF {  CreateDate \@ "MM" } = 12 "1/97" 
"{ = {  CreateDate \@ "MM" } + 1 }/97 } }
{  IF {   = {  REF "Delay" } + { CreateDate \@ "dd" } } <= { REF"DaysInMonth" }
{ CreateDate \@ "MMMM { = {  REF "Delay" } + { CreateDate \@ "dd" } }, yyyy"}{ QUOTE { NextMonth \@ "MMMM" } 
{ = { REF "Delay" } + { CreateDate \@ "dd" } - { REF"DaysInMonth" } }, 
{ IF { CreateDate \@ "MM" } <> 12 { CreateDate \@ "yyyy" }
{ CreateDate \@ "{ = 1 + { CreateDate \@ "yyyy" } \# "xxxx" }" } } } }" }
```

I am trying this in Word 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I add an **image** here with the correct formatting to make sure that you can see the right formatting as this sometimes gets corrupted pasting it in.

[image]

This will give (today when I wrote this): 11/6/2016

Remember that the braces {} cannot be simply typed in from the keyboard, you have to get Word to insert them using Ctrl-F9 or some other method. Alt-F9 toggles display of all field codes. F9 updates field codes

Also keep in mind that Regional Formatting is an important part to keep track off. In my case above, the Round function takes the comma as decimal separator and semi-colon as list separator. This might be different in your location!
Another thing to check is the double quotes, make sure these are the real double-quotes not the **‘Word’** double quotes: **“”**

I can't paste in the code as Word Field formatting is not just clear text. You need to type it over (with exception of the braces, use Ctrl-F9 for that!) to make it work properly. A lot of work and you need to check everything very carefully. It took me quite some time to get it right myself!

Comment: There's a closing bracket missing in the `MOD()` clause: `MOD( { CREATEDATE \@ "yy" }, 4 ) }` -- also, see http://www.addbalance.com/word/datefields2.htm for a longer explanation

Comment: Right ... so (as I added the code as an image due to formatting consistency that is kinda important in the editor) make sure to add the closing bracket. Thanks @user1092247